# Not able to create Header in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am not able to created Header in Elementor as i keep getting below error

`“Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.”`

i have a one page website with header on the same page now i want to create Header Template so that i can add same Header to different pages as i have to show some post for that i want to create a second page which will show post and whenever i try to create Header i keep getting above error in elementor.

I am using `Elementor Canvas` for Home Page which i have created so if i  need to add `the_content` function i am not sure where to add it?

UPDATE: It seems issue is due to `ElementsKit Lite` plugin as i have created menu using the same plugin and when i want to create new Header its not letting me so as there is some conflict with this plugin `ElementsKit Lite`

Answer (score 0):

ElementsKit uses Elementor's template function. When creating a header template, are you doing it throuhgh the Elementor Theme Builder?
`Wordpress Admin` > `Templates` > `Theme Builder` > `Add New`

Answer (score 0):

If you are Elementor pro. user navigate to
**Templates** > **Theme Builder** > **Add New** > Select type **Header** from the dropdown menu.

After Design the header design navigate to little top arrow beside **Publish**
Now click on **Display Condition** and add a condition for the **entire site**.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Elementor Canvas? That doesn't show any header or footer.  Instead, use:

- Default (default WP header)
- Elementor (header & footer visible)
- Theme (header & footer based on theme settings or WP default)